# Configuring Maven to support creation of .exe installer

Tags: maven, installation, installshield

I am currently using Maven 3 and have a really simple `.ism` file for **InstallShield 2012**.

My `pom.xml` creates a `.jar` file which is the only file used by the `.ism`.  I can do something like this:

```
C:>IsCmdBld.exe -p "c:\InstallShield Projects\Simple.ism" -r "COMP" -y "1.0"
```

This is of outside of my POM, but I would like to use the version info in the POM and other metadata to in the installer creation.

I'm aware no specific InstallShield plug-in does not exist for Maven, but I'm wondering if there is a way to get Maven to help out by calling the command block above, or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) and pass in the ${project.version} as part of your execution call.

Otherwise if there is an anttask for InstallShield you could use that with the [antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

While the question was asked way in the past, and I haven't had access to InstallShield for a year now, I did happen to work on a Maven plugin to introduce things that you want to achieve.

https://github.com/tptak/installshield-maven-plugin

I could continue work on this to some extent if I had a licence